# Connect to open WiFi manually without the use of dhcpcd or NetworkManager

Tags: networking, wifi, dhcp

How can I connect my RPi to my open WiFi ("FreeHotspot") without the use of dhcpcd or NetworkManager?
I tried using python library wifi but without any success.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need/want `dhcpcd` (the current default network manager) to "interfere" with your manual network configuration experiments, that is simple enough to accomplish:

###### Declare & configure a static configuration in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`

A static configuration in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` effectively tells `dhcpcd` *"butt out - I've got this..."*. A static config will look something like this (ref `man dhcpcd.conf`):

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.0.10/24
static ip6_address=fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::ff/64
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8 fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::1
```

I'm not sure what your objective is, but I believe this answers the question as you've stated it.

Comment: I have a Raspberry Pi Zero 2W with dhcpcd5 and network-manager packages purged. Should your approach work even under this case?

Comment: @Gouz: I *have no idea* what you mean by `network-manager packages purged`. However, I can tell you this with certainty: It's a quick and easy test to check it out, and if my answer doesn't work, it's easy enough to undo: simply *comment out* the static config lines (there may already be commented-out lines in your default conf file). Try it - if it doesn't fix your problem, add the results of your test to your question & we'll try something else.